# H2 CSVREAD not separating field correctly when double quotes in values

Tags: java, h2

I am trying to load field delimited values using H2 CSVREAD.But it appears that CSVREAD is not parsing the values as expected when there are double quotes. 
Here is the simple example

H2 Version : 1.4.190

SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM CSVREAD('data/test.dat','COL1~COL2','fieldSeparator=~')

test.dat file contents:

"abcd"ao~xyz

"efgh"bo~ijk

Actual Result:

COL1|COL2

abcd|ao

efgh|bo

Expected Result:

COL1|COL2

"abcd"ao|xyz

"abcd"bo|xyz

Looks like this is happening only when there is double quote followed by some value. Is there a way to work this?

**Update:**
Resolved by adding fieldDelimiter= option to CSVREAD.

SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM CSVREAD('data/test.dat','COL1~COL2','fieldSeparator=~ **fieldDelimiter=**')

Comment: The [default field delimiter](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#csv_options) is a double quote...

Comment: @ThomasMueller Thank you for reference.Resolved the issue.